# How to get Data from Node-RED/ Octoblu to Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-eventhub, node-red, azure-stream-analytics

Trying to get a live dashboard of the state of my gates (ON, OFF)

The JSON format of my payload is

```
"msg": {
      "time_on": 1437773972742,
      "time_off": 1437773974231,
}
```

Does anyone have experience on how to send the states to power bi without using Azure Stream Analytics or Event Hub?

Edit:
Trying to send two json packages from Node-Red to Power BI to get live updates on my dashboard

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do here. Please add some more detail about what you have already tried

Comment: @hardillb does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Stream Analytics you will need to flatten the properties by doing SELECT msg.time_on, msg.time_off FROM Input.

If you don't want to use Stream Analytics you will either need to push the data to one of the sources that Power BI can periodically pull from such as SQL Azure (Note: this will not be real time) or integrate with the Power BI push API by going through the resources here: http://dev.powerbi.com.

Ziv.

Comment: hey thx. i check out the powerbi dev section but I am new to software , db, and json.  Can you please elaborate with an example how i can send it from Node-RED to power BI.

Comment: I unfortunately don't know Node-RED and can't provide a sample but hopefully someone else in the community can help...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Node-RED either; but there a pretty good samples here: https://github.com/PowerBI.  You can also use our API Console (http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/) to play with the API.  The console can generate code for you in common languages like JavaScript, Ruby, Python, C#, etc.

Look at Create Dataset:
http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets/datasets-collection/create-a-dataset

and add rows to a table:
http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets/table-rows/add-rows-to-a-table-in-a-dataset

HTH, Lukasz